# magento2.1 Problem with shipping address on checkout page

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-address

I have a customer with 3 addresses.

In address 1 street is blank. When I am going to place order i am selecting other 2 address which has proper address but it check always 1 record and gives Error.

> Error ::
>
> "Street Address" is a required value. "Street Address" length must be
>   equal or greater than 1 characters.

Is there any solution.